# Apply shading, formatting and borders to pivoted dataframe

Tags: dataframe, formatting, pivot

I have the following data that has been pivoted:

```
pip install Jinja2

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import rec, nan

a=rec.array([('FY20',  361.410592  ,  nan, 21.97, nan, 'Total', 'Fast'),
       ('FY21',  359.26952604,  -1., 22.99,  5., 'Total', 'Fast'),
       ('FY22',  362.4560529 ,   1., 22.77, -1., 'Total', 'Fast'),
       ('FY23',  371.53543252,   2., 21.92, -4., 'Total', 'Fast'),
       ('FY24',  374.48894494,   1., 21.88, -0., 'Total', 'Fast'),
       ('FY25',  377.09481613,   1., 21.85, -0., 'Total', 'Fast'),
       ('FY20',   67.043756  ,  nan, 21.  , nan, 'Homes', 'Fast'),
       ('FY21',  110.12145222,  63., 20.95, -0., 'Homes', 'Fast'),
       ('FY22',  117.46526727,   7., 20.73, -1., 'Homes', 'Fast'),
       ('FY23',  125.83482531,   7., 18.99, -8., 'Homes', 'Fast'),
       ('FY24',  126.16748411,   1., 18.95, -0., 'Homes', 'Fast'),
       ('FY25',  127.786528  ,   1., 18.96,  0., 'Homes', 'Fast'),
       ('FY20',  294.366836  ,  nan, 22.19, nan, 'Businesses', 'Fast'),
       ('FY21',  249.14807381, -15., 23.89,  8., 'Businesses', 'Fast'),
       ('FY22',  245.99078563,  -2., 23.74, -1., 'Businesses', 'Fast'),
       ('FY23',  245.70060721,   0., 23.42, -1., 'Businesses', 'Fast'),
       ('FY24',  247.32146083,   1., 23.37, -0., 'Businesses', 'Fast'),
       ('FY25',  250.30828813,   1., 23.33, -0., 'Businesses', 'Fast'),
       ('FY20',  184.631684  ,  nan, 15.47, nan, 'Total', 'Medium'),
       ('FY21',  274.25718084,  49., 15.53,  0., 'Total', 'Medium'),
       ('FY22',  333.23835913,  21., 15.33, -1., 'Total', 'Medium'),
       ('FY23',  357.33167549,   7., 15.52,  1., 'Total', 'Medium'),
       ('FY24',  367.84796426,   3., 15.53,  0., 'Total', 'Medium'),
       ('FY25',  370.1664439 ,   1., 15.53,  0., 'Total', 'Medium'),
       ('FY20',   46.522416  ,  nan, 17.89, nan, 'Homes', 'Medium'),
       ('FY21',   97.63428522, 112., 18.72,  5., 'Homes', 'Medium'),
       ('FY22',  141.25547499,  46., 17.86, -5., 'Homes', 'Medium'),
       ('FY23',  157.06766598,  11., 18.33,  3., 'Homes', 'Medium'),
       ('FY24',  163.02337094,   4., 18.29, -0., 'Homes', 'Medium'),
       ('FY25',  165.98360465,   1., 18.28, -0., 'Homes', 'Medium'),
       ('FY20',  138.109268  ,  nan, 14.66, nan, 'Businesses', 'Medium'),
       ('FY21',  177.62289562,  28., 13.77, -6., 'Businesses', 'Medium'),
       ('FY22',  191.98288414,   8., 13.46, -2., 'Businesses', 'Medium'),
       ('FY23',  200.26400951,   4., 13.31, -1., 'Businesses', 'Medium'),
       ('FY24',  203.82459332,   2., 13.31,  0., 'Businesses', 'Medium'),
       ('FY25',  205.18283926,   1., 13.31,  0., 'Businesses', 'Medium')],
      dtype=[('FY', 'O'), ('ADV', '<f8'), ('YoY_ADV', '<f8'), ('Yield', '<f8'), ('YoY_Yld', '<f8'), ('Cut', 'O'), ('Product', 'O')])

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df1=pd.melt(df, id_vars=['FY','Product','Cut'], var_name="Metric", value_name="Value")
df2 = pd.pivot(df1, index=['Metric', 'Product','Cut'],columns=['FY'],values=['Value'])
df2
```

And looks like this:

[image]

I want to apply table styles so I can copy/paste a polished table into PowerPoint but need the following:

1. **Shade columns** FY23, FY24, FY25 in orange
2. **Apply formatting**: Metric=ADV rounded to **zero decimals**, Metric=Yield to **2 decimals**, and each of YoY_ADV plus YoY_Yld to **1 decimal place**
3. **Negative numbers red**, otherwise black
4. **Apply frame** around table.

Here is my code but I am getting error 'Cannot index with multidimensional key':

```
    # 1. If numbers are negative, make red otherwise black
#####################################################
def color_negative_red(x):
    if x < 0:
      return 'color: red'
    else: 
      return 'color: black'

# 2. Slide major metrics so formatting can be applied
######################################################
adv_slice=df2.loc[('ADV', slice(None)), :]
yld_slice=df2.loc[('Yield', slice(None)), :]
yoy_adv_slice=df2.loc[('YoY_ADV', slice(None)), :]
yoy_yld_slice=df2.loc[('YoY_Yld', slice(None)), :]

#3. Apply table style  
#####################
df2.style.applymap(color_negative_red).set_properties(**{'background-color': 'orange'}, subset=['FY23','FY24','FY25']).format('{:.0f}', subset=adv_slice, na_rep='-').format('{:.2f}', subset=yld_slice, na_rep='-').format('{:.1f}', subset=(yoy_adv_slice,yoy_yld_slice), na_rep='-').set_table_styles([{'selector': '',
                    'props' : [('border','1px solid black')]},
                  {'selector': 'th',
                    'props' : [('border','1px solid black')]},
                  {'selector': 'td',
                    'props' : [('border','1px solid black')]}]).set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})
```

What is needed to make the code work?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

With some mods:

```
    [![# 1. If numbers are negative, make red otherwise black
#####################################################
def color_negative_red(x):
    if x < 0:
      return 'color: red'
    else: 
      return 'color: black'

#2. Apply table style  
#####################
df2.style.applymap(color_negative_red).set_properties(**{'background-color': 'orange'}, subset=\['FY23','FY24','FY25'\]).\
                 format('{:.0f}', subset=('ADV',), na_rep='-').\
                 format('{:.2f}', subset=('Yield',), na_rep='-').\
                 format('{:.1f}', subset=('YoY_ADV',), na_rep='-').\
                 format('{:.1f}', subset=('YoY_Yld',), na_rep='-').\
                 set_table_styles(\[{'selector': '',
                    'props' : \[('border','0.1px solid black')\]},
                  {'selector': 'th',
                    'props' : \[('border','0.5px solid black')\]},
                  {'selector': 'td',
                    'props' : \[('border','0.5px solid black')\]}\]).set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})][1]][1]
```